# Using PyFolio alongside Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I aim to do a time series analysis of financial data. Since I am working on Pakistan Stock Exchange (PSX), data is not available on yahoo. When I looked at some tutorials on Quantopian, the first step, data extraction is done through yahoo finance. 
Now when I use PyFolio module and read in csv (Panda's Function) containing data, there is an issue with datetime format of Pandas and PyFolio. Below is the code of what I am doing.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pyfolio as pf
import datetime
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

start_date = '2015-02-01'
end_date = '2017-03-20'
live_date = '2017-03-15'
symbols = ['KEL']

def converter(start_date):
    convert=datetime.strptime(start_date, "%Y-%m-%d")
    return convert

def data(symbols):
    dates=pd.date_range(start_date,end_date) 
    df=pd.DataFrame(index=dates)
    df_temp=pd.read_csv('/home/furqan/Desktop/python_data/{}.csv'.format(str(symbols[0])),usecols=['Date','Close'],
                            parse_dates=True,index_col='Date',na_values=['nan'])
    df_temp = df_temp.rename(columns={'Close': symbols[0]})
    df=df.join(df_temp)
    df=df.fillna(method='ffill')
    df=df.fillna(method='bfill')
    return df
new_date = converter (live_date)
df= data(symbols)
sheet = pf.create_returns_tear_sheet(df, live_start_date=new_date)
```

The above code leads to following error

```
TypeError: Cannot compare tz-naive and tz-aware timestamps
```

Given the above information I have two questions.

1) Can Quantopian be any good for my analysis if I have data on my PC? Since the data is not available on yahoo finance.

2)What does the above error exactly means? How can I fix this error.

For reference below is the link to PyFolio and Pandas documentation.
https://quantopian.github.io/pyfolio/notebooks/single_stock_example/#fetch-the-daily-returns-for-a-stock

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got around this problem by adding TZ information to my series. If you know the timezone of your datetime index you can apply the following method:

```
df.tz_localize('UTC')
```

I hope it helps.